# clang.cindex.LibclangError "Undefined symbol clang_CXXRecord_isAbstract"

Tags: python, c++, linux, llvm-clang

I am trying to execute clang 5.0 with the next commands but it does not work.. I typed:

```
import clang

import clang.cindex

clang.cindex.Config.set_library_file('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-5.0.so.1')

id = clang.cindex.Index.create()
```

and I received the following error:

> clang.cindex.LibclangError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-5.0.so.1: undefined symbol: clang_CXXRecord_isAbstract. Please ensure that your python bindings are compatible with your libclang.so version.

I am using clang-5.0 with the bindings from https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Any update ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Windows**

I haven't tested this right now, but it worked a month ago for me.

1. Either download the [src code](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang) from github and go to /bindings/python/ and copy the clang directory and paste it into your python site packages dir **or (try both)** `pip install clang-5`
2. Download the [llvm binares](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html). If you have python-32bit then install llvm 32bit!! Otherwise it wont work. For 64bit python install the 64bit binaries
3. In your python program just `import clang.cindex as cl` and in your code do `cl.Config.set_library_file("your/path/to/libclang.dll")` 
   libclang.dll should be in your clang/bin installation directory

**Linux**

Running it right now, so it works for me

1. `pip3 install clang-5`
2. from your package manager either get llvm-clang or llvm-clang-32bit
   depending on your python installation
3. In your python program just `import clang.cindex as cl` and in your code do `cl.Config.set_library_file("your/path/to/libclang.so")`

From my experience libclang.so should be located in either /usr/lib32/ or usr/lib64/

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works perfect! I was not aware of pip for clang-5. I was using the source code of clang directly from Github. Thanks! You saved me a lot of time!

Comment: It still does not work. Now the error is: ''clang.cindex.LibclangError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang.so: undefined symbol: clang_CXXConstructor_isConvertingConstructor. Please ensure that your python bindings are compatible with your libclang.so version.

Comment: @mvsa which llvm version's binaries have you downloaded? Hopefully not from the new 6.0. Try 5.0.1

Comment: I downloaded 5.0.1 version. Finally it works. Thank you very much!